# How to fix this graphic error with Chrome 36 on Mac OS 10.9.4?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, graphics, rendering

Time and time again Chrome 36 on Mac OS 10.9.4 seems to have problems to render the graphics properly (see image below). This distortion is visible only for some time. As soon as the contents change the graphics are rendered properly.

I have this problem only on my private MBP (Early 2010). The MBP (Late 2011) I use at work does not have this problem. The problem often shows when I watch YouTube videos in Chrome. It sometimes happens in Safari too. I guess it is a problem with my Mac OS configuration/graphic card driver. But I don't even know where to look for a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These questions describe problems similar to yours and have solutions that may fix your problem:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/144175/4018

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45671/interference-on-external-vga-monitor-intermittent-ripple-only-when-booted-into